# docker - how can we export/import (or save/load) only the new changes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtualization

I'm new to docker, Could any one help for below query

1. Server has a docker image like 1GB Image:ver1 [this image stored has .tar file in server]
2. In ubuntu PC donwloaded the tar image form server and loads/import the image[Image:ver1] using Docker
3. A new Image:ver2 is available on the Serever, size is still 1GB but difference with ver1 is only 10MB.

Q1: If it’s possible to “import/load” the new image[Image:ver2] from server, how can we export/import (or save/load) only the new changes[i.e 10MB]?

Q2: if we are able to apply above changes on top o existing image[i.e Image:Ver1], what are the steps to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save/load tar files of docker images, there's no option to export a partial image. You can send over the full image, move your data to be an external volume that isn't transfered this way, or you can use a docker registry.

The latter is relatively easy to implement, docker includes [an image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) where you can run your own private registry. Pushes and pulls to a docker registry will only send the changed layers, so you can make use of layer caching and structure your Dockerfiles to minimize the number of changed layers.

Comment: did any option appear in 2019? :)

Comment: @gleam The registry server always has been the better option, Docker rarely develops new features for parts of the code that don't fit best practices. But it's open source, you can always create something.

Comment: thx. I have to deploy a docker-app on the PC without internet (data is transpored by flash drive!). So the registry is not working for my case :(

Comment: @gleam While you're creating a better solution to your problem, consider how you will know from the internet connection machine what files you already have on the disconnected machine? What if you want to take that same partial export to a third machine in a different starting state?

Comment: the answer is simple - my docker-app has release versions :)

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a file based system and for each Pull request, it only pulls out the files which are changed. For example, if suppose you have 1 GB data in a file in a docker image. Now, you added 500MB of data to it. Then, in case of docker pull, it will only pull the changes, i.e the *Delta* part between the 2 files. So, you are safe and it won't pull all the things separately.

Although, while making a DockerFile, or docker conf file, you should be very careful, as all the lines in a Docker file is stored as a layer in the system. If suppose you have 10 layers in your Docker file, and you are changing the 5th layer, then all the layers after the 5th layer will again be pulled. That is the only catch using Docker.
Rest, it will always pull the Delta of changes for each pull request.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have understand your reply regarding Push and pull docker commands,  i have query only export/import, save/load commands

For example:

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have understood about Push and pull docker commands,  i have query only export/import, save/load commands

For example:
Downloaded image[image_ver1.tar] file from server
docker load < image_ver1.tar file,  it is having 1GB

After soem days server have new image[image_v2.tar], this ver2 image have only 10MB Data changes comapre to ver1 image

Q1: is it possible to merge only 10MB data changes from ver2 to ver1 ?
Q2: If possible , how to merge?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with exported image tarballs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've built the [tool](https://github.com/seovchinnikov/docker_tar_layer_diff) to create diff (in top layers) of docker images' versions (layer by layer) as a tarball and inflate the original image later.

Note. Works only for changes in **top layers**.

4-step process:

1. docker inspect -> make json with old layers' hashes as a json file
2. Prepare diff based on new image and hashes of old (existing) layers
3. Transfer diff to target machine
4. Inflate target image's tar based on diff and old image

Comment: You should include the most relevant steps from the readme *directly in the answer*. An answer with the useful content largely on some external resource is not very useful, especially if the link ever becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is to use a local 'Docker Registry' as an intermediary. Run a 'registry:latest' on your system. See the [official guide](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry-2/).

Then push the base image and your derived image to the same registry. You'll see that derived images will only export the new layers to the registry.
On the target machine pulling the derived image, while having the base image, will only pull in the missing layers.